# Continuity of piecewise function using topology

Tags: calculus, general-topology, functions

I would like to check if what I'm doing is correct or if I'm missing something:

Given the two sets $$X = [0,1] \cup (2,3], \quad Y = [0,2],$$ both equipped with the standard topology, consider the function $f:X \to Y$ defined by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if $x \in [0,1]$} \\ x-1 & \text{if $x \in (2,3]$} \end{cases}.$$

Show that $f$ is bijective from $X$ to $Y$ and continuous, but that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous.

- To show that $f$ is continuous, I take the open interval $V = (0,2)$ and find that $\operatorname{Preim}_f(V) = (0,1) \cup (2,3)$, which is open since it's the union of two open sets.
- To see that $f$ is bijective, I find the map $$g(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if $x \in [0,1]$} \\ x+1 & \text{if $x \in (1,2]$} \end{cases},$$ which is the inverse of $f(x)$. Since I found an inverse, then $f$ is bijective.
- Now, what open subset can I consider in order to show that $g = f^{-1}$ is not continuous?

Are the first 2 parts complete, or am I missing anything?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first part is incomplete. All you have shown is that there exists *one* open subset of the codomain such that its preimage is open.
However, you have to show that that is the case for *all* open subsets of $[0, 2]$.
(The pasting/glueing lemma may be helpful here.)

---

To show that the inverse is not continuous, consider the open set $\left(\dfrac12, 1\right] \subset X$.
(Why is this open?)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For the first point, I don't see which subsets to "glue", since the union which defines $X$ has an empty intersection... could you elaborate a bit further, please? :)
Also, $(1/2,1] \subset X$ is open because of the subset topology , correct?

Comment: The gluing lemma doesn't necessarily require the "components" to be intersecting. So you may take $[0, 1]$ and $(2, 3]$. For the second part, your reasoning is correct. :)

Comment: I feel my previous comment might've been too hasty in regards to the second part. While it is true that $(1/2, 1] \subset X$ is open because the topology is the subspace one, you still would have to justify why that is open in the subspace topology. One way to do so would be to show that it is the intersection of $X$ with an open set (of $\Bbb R$).

Answer (score 1):

@Aryaman has already given an answer. An alternate approach which does not require hunting for open sets is the following.

We have the map $f^{-1}:[0, 2]\to [0, 1]\cup (2, 3]$ whihc is bijective and hence in particular surjective.

If $f^{-1}$ were continuous then $f^{-1}$ would be a continuous function on an interval whose image is not connected. This contradicts the fact that the continuous image of any connected topological space is a connected space.